# How to communicate between two windows?

Tags: qt, qt5

I am new to Qt. Using Qt Creator 3.1.1 based on Qt 5.4.1 on Ubuntu 15.04.

My trying to build an application which lists employees on main screen with Add, Edit, Delete and Export buttons on right side. On click of Add and Edit buttons, opens another child window and performs respective action.

I want to refresh employee list on main window once user adds/edits/deletes employee from child window.

I do not want to write entire code in single file so separated code according to screens. But I am not sure how to access parent window UI elements from child window. So I achieved this using code below from child file.

```
QTableWidget *tableWidget   = this->parent()->findChild<QTableWidget *>();
QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("SELECT * FROM employees order by id DESC");

    tableWidget->setRowCount( 0 );
    tableWidget->setRowCount( query.size() );
    tableWidget->setColumnWidth( 0, 60 );
    tableWidget->setColumnWidth( 1, 200 );
    tableWidget->setColumnWidth( 2, 150 );
    tableWidget->setColumnWidth( 3, 100 );

    while( query.next() ) {

        tableWidget->setItem( columnCount, 0 ,new QTableWidgetItem( query.value(0).toString() ) );
        tableWidget->setItem( columnCount, 1 ,new QTableWidgetItem( query.value(1).toString() ) );
        tableWidget->setItem( columnCount, 2 ,new QTableWidgetItem( query.value(2).toString() ) );
        tableWidget->setItem( columnCount, 3 ,new QTableWidgetItem( query.value(3).toString() ) );

        columnCount++;
    }
```

[click here for screenshot of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VC5P.png)

Is this correct approach to achieve this functionality? Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: The same way you would communicate between any two objects - using Qt's signals and slots mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Your secondary window can just emit a signal which you connect to a slot in your main window and that slot executed the code you have there.

Or, if those additional windows are modal dialogs (blocking the user from interacting with the main window while open), then just trigger the update after they return from the `exec()` calls